# What would happen if I send a query while renaming MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say I have MongoDB collection A and B, and they are in the same database.

I'm renaming B to A with deleting target.

I know renaming takes really short time.

But what if I send a query to A while mongo is still renaming B to A?

```
----------|--------------------------------|---------------------------|-------------------

   rename B to A begin              Send query to A             rename B to A done
```

Am I gonna get the result right away? or wait till the end of rename?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.renameCollection/)

> The db.collection.renameCollection() method and renameCollection command will invalidate open cursors which interrupts queries that are currently returning data.

So you might end up with errors of dead or killed cursors while renaming your collection.

Since MongoDB 4.2, all operations will wait on the rename to be finished.

> renameCollection() obtains an exclusive lock on the source and target collections for the duration of the operation. All subsequent operations on the collections must wait until renameCollection() completes. Prior to MongoDB 4.2, renaming a collection within the same database with renameCollection required obtaining an exclusive database lock.